# segregating solr indexes for each end-user

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, search-engine, solr4

For our we application we would like to somehow segregate index data for each user using the application (which is using solr to index uploaded data). Is that possible?

The schema.xml and the document structure for all the documents being indexed are same. We just want segregate for security reasons.

clarification: I forgot to mention that the solr is only accessible by the web app. The end user never connects to the Solr directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each document can be accessed only by a handful of users, you can keep a multi-valued field of user IDs `allowed_user_ids` who are allowed to access the document. Then do a filter query on it by user_id to restrict access.

If you have both public and restricted documents, then instead of storing all user_id's in the public documents, you can keep a field `is_public` and set it to true for the public documents only. For the restricted documents, use the filter query on `allowed_user_ids`.

Comment: I am little confused with your response. Is allowed_user_ids a built-in Solr field to control ACLs?

Comment: No, you need to add it when you index the data.

Comment: This will need to be added to the schema. You will need to define new field(s) to accomodate this and then populate the new field(s) accordingly.

Comment: This is indeed probably the best option. Solr isn't really build for having lots of indices (one per user) last time I checked, bc. of pretty big overhead per index. The official term for this btw is 'multi tenancy' if you ever want to google for more info.

Comment: Thanks guys. We already have a field in the schema.xml that indicates the owner of the document. we use that in the application to prevent one user from seeing document for other users in the search results. Is this the best approach? Am I worrying unnecessarily about the security?

Comment: Since only your web app knows the Solr IP, I guess you don't need to worry about security, as long as you filter by user_id before issuing the Solr query. You can read for general tips at https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using search-space filter feature of the Lucene. It restricts the document-set available to search, for a query, based on provided criteria.

The criteria can be constructed in two ways.

1) just like any other Lucene query : [Lucene Filtered Query](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FilteredQuery.html)

2) Pass in the document-set to the IndexSearcher as an instance of [Filter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_1_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Filter.html)